# Inotify dynamically index new folders

Tags: linux, bash, inotify

Say for example you had a shell script that utilises inotifywait in the following form

```
inotifywait -m -e create /home/user1/*/*
```

Essentially you are asking it to monitor all folders two levels under user1. I've noticed with inotify that it can not dynamically index new folders.

For example you have a file system like

```
/home
     /user1
           /a
             /b
```

Then you run the inotifywait script, it will monitor actions on the 'b' folder.
If you were to then add a new folder 'c' under 'a' (same level as 'b'), inotify will not monitor actions on this folder. Anyone got a way of remedying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go up a level and monitor that with the recursive switch.

```
inotifywait -r -m -e create /home/user1/*
```

I don't know what you are using this for, but for indefinite watching you might want to check out [iwatch](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Comment: When i used /home/user1/* its say no suh file or directory.below is my Code        MONITORDIR="/home/truecom/Desktop/inputfiles/*"
inotifywait -m -r -e create  "${MONITORDIR}" | while read NEWFILE
do
        echo "New file Name is " |  ${NEWFILE};
done